# Hiding Tab Bar Controller On A Subview

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, subview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have found lot's of variations for this question but just wanted some clarity on it as I can't seem to get mine working.

I have a TabBarController (TBC) which contains several `UIViewController`s (Each Tab). On one of these `UIViewController`s (mainMenu), I am trying to add another `UIViewController` (game1) as a subview:

```
[self.view addSubview:game1.view];
```

Now the issue with this is that it takes the TBC with it, so I tried hiding it using:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; //< (In the game1.m ViewDidLoad method)
```

and

```
game1.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; //< (In the mainMenu.m after I initialise game1)
```

I am guessing that this is due to the menu never being pushed as I am using the addSubview approach?

Originally I was using the `presentModalViewController` approach but the frame is being passed onto the new view, thus causing the UI layout to be offset / zoomed in.

Can anyone help me fix this issue, I can't seem to hide the TBC and am running out of ideas.

Thanks in advanced, Elliott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is only relevant when you're pushing the view controller onto a `UINavigationController` stack. What you're doing with the `addSubview:` is that you're just adding the view of `game1` into the current view controller's view. That is not right at all and UIKit won't handle that at all.

You should put a `UINavigationController` as the view controller for your tab, then push the `game1` view controller with something like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:game1 animated:YES];
```

instead of `addSubview:`. That will then work with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. Note however that it's probably best to set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the your `init` method of whatever class `game1` is, rather than in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So instead of having numerous UIViewControllers for the tab items (mainMenu etc), these should be NavigationControllers?

Comment: If you want to push on other view controllers, then yes, that would be the usual way to go about things. You can hide the actual navigation bar on the "home screen" if you want and then just show it when you push a view controller. That might be the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, moved house at the weekend! Okay thanks for the help, I will update my code and try to structure it in this format to see if I can get the desired affect. All I literally wanted was to be able to show a view without the TabBar because when it comes to showing the game screens I no longer want users to be able to navigate the menus. The issue was really with the nib layout being shown off center due to the change in screen dimensions when I pushed a non tab bar view onto a tab bar one.

Comment: It sounds like you need to just sit down and think about your UI hierarchy. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like presenting modally is what you want. If that's causing the frame of the modal VC to be wrong, then you should look at the XIB / view loading code for that view and see what is wrong. Look at the resizing masks in particular.